# Request using .NET HttpClient request does not receiving response while via browser it does - possible SSL issue?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls1.2, dotnet-httpclient

I'm developing an app and it access a website with HTTPS.

Requesting manually via incognito window, works.
Requesting via app using HttpClient, it never received a response.

I confirmed, via Fiddle, that headers are exactly the same between manual and app request. Via browser, a return comes in 1 second. Via app, it just hangs until eventually times out with an HTTP error 504. It is the exact same URL and exact same HTTP headers, checked one by one.

It is not a deadlock issue because in this case Fiddle would at least show the request completed. However the request stays open until it errors with HTTP 504.

Is it possible that the problem lies in the SSL process? There I noticed differences (in Fiddle). Both are TLS/1.2 version 3.3. The one via browser has SessionID, while the one via app this SessionID is empty. It is also missing some other data like ALPN, etc.
This would be the only thing I can think of, because the request is exactly the same.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE: I was using user-agent as Chrome browser (desktop). I changed the user-agent to Android and now it connects (delivering the mobile version of the page, as expected).

So it seems the server is doing/requiring something special during the connection when browser is desktop, that HttpClient is unable to handle. Connection get stuck with user-agent as desktop (e.g. Chrome) and ends up being cancelled. Changing the user-agent to Android bypassed this and the connection was established. Still, the main issue remains: what is happening that HttpClient is failing when user-agent is desktop?